# Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file

Tags: android, jenkins, emulation

Headless Linux 64-bit. Jenkins is trying to create android emulator but fails with these settings:

```
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux
[android] Creating Android AVD: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_120_768x1200_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_23_google_apis-x86.avd
[android] /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -f -a -s 768x1200 -n hudson_en-US_120_768x1200_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_23_google_apis-x86 -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23" --abi google_apis/x86_64
[android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file
```

Also tried other ABI's for same device: armeabi_v7 and google_apis/x86

I am trying to create this device like that because I need Google Play Services.
I was able to create and run emulator with following settings:

```
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux
[android] /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -f -a -s 768x1200 -n hudson_en-US_120_768x1200_android-23_armeabi-v7a -t android-23 --abi armeabi-v7a
[android] Creating Android AVD: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_120_768x1200_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_23_google_apis-x86.avd
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5730,5731 -report-console tcp:5847,max=60 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_120_768x1200_android-23_armeabi-v7a -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'running'
```

But this emulator doesn't support Google Play services (Google Maps to be more specific), so I don't want it.

Comment: Is there a way to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

I found temporary workaround for that:

Create that same device locally (I did it on my personal laptop, a MAC) with Android AVD manager. 
Then copy this newly created device to Linux server `/var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/` folder (`.ini` and `.avd` folder).

And it worked, also Google Maps is supported.

Comment: As far as I know the real problem for this lies in the fact that Jenkins runs as a service and as a service cannot run the sdk tools. Trying to find out how to let jenkins run as a user or give access so that it can. Did you find a better way? Id like my builds to be completely automated and not have me create a device each time.

Comment: Was stuck with this for a long time. Thanks!

Comment: @Gert I already have those file : $ ls /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/
hudson_de-DE_160_HVGA_android-18_armeabi-v7a.avd  hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-24_armeabi-v7a_mySuffix.avd
hudson_de-DE_160_HVGA_android-18_armeabi-v7a.ini  hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-24_armeabi-v7a_mySuffix.ini
hudson_de-DE_160_HVGA_android-7.avd               hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-24_mySuffix.avd
hudson_de-DE_160_HVGA_android-7.ini               hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-24_mySuffix.ini

Comment: Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23'
Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux
[android] Creating Android AVD: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android-build-demo/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-23_armeabi-v7a_mySuffix.avd
[android] /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -f -a -c 64M -s

Comment: WVGA800 -n hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-23_armeabi-v7a_mySuffix -t android-23 --abi armeabi-v7a
[android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file
Finished: NOT_BUILT

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the similar problem in Mac book pro 13", macOS Sierra; version 10.12.3. I deleted the system environment variables for location to android sdk & gradle previously which I added. When I built it with `system environment variables`; Jenkins downloaded the sdk & it run without failure.

You can also refer to the book `Expert Android Studio by Murat Yener, Onur Dundar` chapter 10 : Continuous integration; where they showed how to build on Jenkins.