# Jenkins: could not create Android emulator failed to parse AVD config file

Tags: android, jenkins

I have a Jeknins installation on my local PC. I'm successfully able to integrate Android application code with github and generate .apk file as an artifact. 
The problem is in the test case execution. I cannot get the Android emulator to start.
It says:

\sdk/tools/android.bat" create avd -f -a -c 500M -s 480x640 -n hudson_en-US_480_480x640_android-21_armeabi-v7a -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
[android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file
Recording test result.

I have already tried this:
[Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180910/could-not-create-android-emulator-failed-to-parse-avd-config-file)

Also, I ran the same create command from command line and it successfully craeted the AVD.

Comment: Why don't you use the android emulator plugin? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin

Comment: I am using it. This is the output from the console i'm pasting here. 
Maybe its a problem with the plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, but it seems that the andoid Sdk update that came out recently - SDK Tools, Revision 25.3.0 (March 2017) - has made some significant changes.

The Android emulator jenkins plugin uses the *android* command (*/home/jenkins/Android/Sdk/tools/android*), but if I copy the commands from the console output and try and run that from the command line on the Jenkins machine I get:

```
[android] /home/jenkins/Android/Sdk/tools/android create avd -f -a -s HVGA -n hudson_en-US_120_HVGA_7.02 -t 7.02
[android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file
```

and try and run that from the command line on the Jenkins machine I get:

```
The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
```

So it seems that from 25.3.0 onwards, the 'android' command is deprecated and has been removed, but the emulator plugin hasn't been updated to reflect this.

As a solution, the best bet seems to be to install an earlier version of the android Sdk that still supports the 'android' command, at least until the plugin is updated.

Comment: I think I tried with the earlier version. But I will try again and let you know about this. Thanks!

Comment: @Hadi another possibility I've seen suggested is that you might need some 32 bit libraries if you are running a 64 bit OS : see second answer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278685/jenkins-fails-to-create-new-android-emulator-failed-to-parse-avd-config-file

Comment: The same problem for me, I think that you're probably right about SDK update.

Comment: This problem was valid! I downgraded the build tools verison. But in the end this wasn't the solution, the answer by Gert in the following question solved it!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180910/could-not-create-android-emulator-failed-to-parse-avd-config-file

Thanks! :)

Comment: In the end, i skipped the ' run an emulator option'  and it automatically connects to any/all running/connected android emulators/devices. Not a perfect solution but enables you to complete the integration process.

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the sdcard field empty.

I ran the command that the android plugin printed out via a shell script and added -v (for verbose) after android.
I then saw that the problem was that it could not create an sdcard.

When not filling in an sdcard size, it worked.