# Can't get to work Android emulator Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

**With Android Emulator Plugin**

*x86*

[image]

```
/home/ubuntu/tools/android-sdk/tools/android create avd -f -a -c 256M -s WVGA800 -n hudson_en-US_480_WVGA_android-23_x86 -t android-23 --abi x86
```

> [android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD
>   config file

Same with `armeabi-v7a`

I've tried all of these things from these posts that seem to work to other people but not to me:

[Jenkins: could not create Android emulator failed to parse AVD config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608653/jenkins-could-not-create-android-emulator-failed-to-parse-avd-config-file)

[Jenkins fails to create new Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278685/jenkins-fails-to-create-new-android-emulator-failed-to-parse-avd-config-file)

[Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180910/could-not-create-android-emulator-failed-to-parse-avd-config-file)

**Without emulator plugin**

So after almost two days of frustration I decided not to use the Android Emulator Plugin and try to run it manually. So I copy one of my avds from my local machine to the server and to run it with this command.

```
/home/ubuntu/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5772,5773 -report-console tcp:5863,max=60 -avd Nexus_6_API_23 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
```

An this is the output:

> PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

When I add `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to the system environments:

> PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/home/ubuntu/tools/android-sdk]!

I've look on the internet and this seems to be the right path. So what's the problem? What else should I try?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, there were two main problems:

- Really I never got the Emulator Plugin to create a new AVD. Instead, I created the AVDs from Android studio in my local machine and then copied the `.avd` and `.ini` from `$HOME_LOCAL_MACHINE/.android/avd` to `$HOME_JENKINS_SERVER`/.android/avd`via`scp`and then selected in the Emulator Plugin`Run existing emulator` with the name of the AVD I just copied (without the file extension).
- There were some tools I failed to install from SDKMANAGER. So in my case running a `API 23 arm` emulator I ran `sdkmanager "build-tools;23.0.3" "platforms;android-23" "system-images;android-23;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"`. Just install everything from the API your trying to run and the system image from the corresponding ABI.